# Полноразмерный UITextView в приложении с адаптацией под размер текста?

Tags: ios, uikit

Привет все, меня интересует такой вопрос, есть **UITextView в Master-Detail приложении**. собственно текст выводиться через UITextView в Detail части. Размер текста постоянно меняется. iOS 6, xCode 4.6

Подскажите пожалуйста **как подогнать UItextView под размер текста** но что бы скроллинг был не внутренний, а полностью вeсь Detail. Про способ запихивания в Scroll view всего что есть в Detail - а потом в View - а потом уже элементы знаю но это **не работает с Constraints**(Способ был в программе "Научи Меня Xcode" 2ой или 3ий выпуск).

**Что я пытаюсь сделать?**

Взять Картинку, заголовок, текст (UItextView c разным количествой текста каждый раз в зависимости от ячейки) и запихиваю в View, но текст в UITEXTView больше самой View и мне нужно что бы скроллинг был страничный, а не внутри UITextView.

**p.s.** *Гуглить на буржуйских сайтах пробовал* но проблема настолько спецефична что мне не удалось найти хотя бы толику полезной инфы. В программе "Научи Меня Xcode" способ дельный но он не работает с iOS 6, а только с iOS 5.

**Подойдет все от ссылки на библиотеку до ссылки на solve задачи. Заранее спасибо.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ложите в Detail scrollView в него TextView и при загрузке делаете следующее:

```
CGRect frameTextView = textview.frame;
//установка высоты TextView равной размеру его содержимого 
frameTextView.size.height = textview.contentSize.height;
textview.frame = frameTextView;

self.scroll.contentSize = textview.contentSize;
```

Более детально [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638998/cant-get-the-uitextview-height-dynamically-correct)